# How to call dialog from fragment

Tags: java, android

When I click on **cardview** dialog has to be opened. So this is my **onClick** method in fragment class.

```
public class Entry_Fragment extends Fragment implements 
View.OnFocusChangeListener, View.OnClickListener {    
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view == cdAddWork)
    {       
if(actvEntryCategory.getText().toString().trim().equals("Installation")){

          try {
           InstActivityDialog dlg;
           dlg = new InstActivityDialog(getFragmentManager(),getActivity().getApplicationContext());
           dlg.show();//here I am passing this fragment and context as parameters to the constructor in that dialog.

           }catch (Exception e){                   
           }
        }
    }
}
}
```

**This is my dialog class**

```
public class InstActivityDialog extends Dialog {
public InstActivityDialog(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
    super(context);
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.installation_dialog); //layout for dialog
        setTitle("Installation Activity");
}
}
```

when I click on cardview in fragment, I need to open the dialog. For that In onClick method I call the dialog. I wanted to pass current fragment and context to the dialog.

What mistake I did while passing `fragment` and `context` as parameters to the constructor? And also while receiving argument in the constructor?

How to pass fragment and context as parameters?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you setOnClickListner for CardView?

Comment: yes@NaveenKumarM

Comment: @kalyan can explain more about question

Comment: what you want achieve?

Comment: Is there even a question here?  I see a few statements, but no clear question.  And FWIW, I don't even see a question mark.

Comment: when I click on cardview in fragment, I need to open the dialog. For that In onClick method I call the dialog. I wanted to pass current fragment and context to the dialog.@Prem,@Hemant Parmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dialog is not showing then problem is in line blow.

```
 InstActivityDialog  dlg = new InstActivityDialog(getSupportFragmentManager(),getApplicationContext());
```

Dialog is bind to Activity's Context not Aplication `Context`. So use it like below.

```
 InstActivityDialog  dlg = new InstActivityDialog(getSupportFragmentManager(),getActivity());
    dlg.show();
```

And for better implementation of Dialog with `FragmentManager` i suggest to use [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html).

Comment: I have written like this. please check my oce clearly, and then answer me. dlg = new InstActivityDialog(getFragmentManager(),getActivity().getApplicationContext());

Comment: Thats what i said in answer. Read the second line replace `getActivity().getApp‌​licationContext()` by `getActivity()`.Thx

Comment: I need your email Id @ADM. You save my day. Thank u so much.

Comment: I am here most of the time . You can tag anyone in comments to get their attention.